# Proverbial or not

Tags: expressions

"Whenever you see a deaf man running follow him, he has seen an impending danger not just heard it."- Has anything proverbial in this sentence?

Comment: Let's hope you never see a *dead* man running!  Seriously though 'dead man walking' is an idiom and yours has a certain familiarity, perhaps due to that.

Comment: If it's been repeated twice it's a proverb.

Comment: @HotLicks You can say that again.

Comment: Two repeats do not  a proverb make.

Comment: @HotLicks - This is not a proverb. This is not a proverb. Is that a proverb? Don't be daft.

Comment: It has the sound of a proverb, but it's not. There are many reasons a deaf man might run: he's late for an appointment, a creditor is chasing him, he's paranoid and believes he's being chased by a demon, he's eager to get home before his puppy wets the carpet. Why in heaven's name would we want to follow him? Proverbs contain *truth* or *good advice*: A rolling stone gathers no moss, don't judge a book by its cover, don't count your chickens before they hatch, no use crying over spilt milk, no man is an island, early bird, gift horse, ain't broke, bite the hand, etc, etc., etc.

Comment: I'm just puzzled as to how, if one saw a man running, one would know whether he was deaf. Perhaps if we shout at him and he doesn't answer...?

Answer (score 3):

proverb

> a short, **well-known** pithy saying, stating a general truth or piece of advice
>
> [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=proverb)

Note the word "well-known" in that definition. I don't think this is - at least not in English. However, as prosd says, the phrasing *sounds* quite proverb-like.

Comment: Is it brevity and the soundness of idea behind it that makes an expression a proverb?

Comment: @SyamKumar.V - Look at that definition again. A proverb has to have *all* of  those characteristics.

Comment: Do proverbs have regional bearings,well that is to say a proverb popular in Australia need to be popular in Wales.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard anyone say this, but there's a sort of phrasing which makes a sentence sound proverbial, and this has it.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret this as meaning that one should rely on perception of reality (eyes) rather than on what people say.

***Proverb***:

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/proverb): a short, memorable, and often highly condensed saying embodying, esp with bold imagery, some commonplace fact or experience

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/proverb): a wise saying or precept; a didactic sentence

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proverb): a brief popular saying (such as “Too many cooks spoil the broth”) that gives advice about how people should live or that expresses a belief that is generally thought to be true

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/proverb): a short pithy saying in general use, stating a general truth or piece of advice

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/proverb): a short statement, usually known by many people for a long time, that gives advice or expresses some common truth

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/proverb): a short well-known statement that gives practical advice about life

Many sources consider "well-known" to be essential to a proverb. Therefore, since this statement is not well-known in any English-speaking culture, it would not commonly be regarded as an American/British/etc proverb. However, if there were a culture in which the statement were in common use, it would be considered a proverb in that culture.